# TableView loading more cell when scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a tableView and when user scroll to the last cell more data will be loaded. In willDisplayCell I implemented this code, referenced from similar questions in stack overflow. But when I scroll to the bottom, it is not loading data once, it creates a loop and calls loadMore function more than once.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastData = self.data!.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastData {
        currentPage += 1
        self.loadData(currentPage)
    }
}

func loadData() {
    self.showLoadingView() 
    apiCALL(callback: { data
      self.jsonDATA.append(contentsOf: data)
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add code of `loadData` method?

Comment: How many sections do you have?

Comment: @trungduc added. 1 section

Comment: Please show me `numberOfRowInSection` method and `showLoadingView` method

Comment: FYI - autoloading more data when scrolling to the bottom is a poor user experience. Let the user choose to load more if they want.

Comment: The method "loadData" you used in tableView willDisplayCell is different that you described it later in the the question. Please refine it and provide more information you used in tableView like  numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean parameter to avoid infinite loop.

```
var isLoading = false

func loadData() {
    isLoading = true
    self.showLoadingView()
    apiCALL(callback: { data
        self.isLoading = false
        self.jsonDATA.append(contentsOf: data)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastData = self.data!.count - 1
    if !isLoading && indexPath.row == lastData {
        currentPage += 1
        self.loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: but you are setting isLoading = false is apiCall and check it if false in willDisplay. So isn't it going to call loadData() continuosly?