# Limit the amount of cells shown in tableView, load more cells when scroll to last cell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to set up a table view that only shows a specific amount of cells.  Once that cell has been shown, the user can keep scrolling to show more cells.  As of right now I'm retrieving all the JSON data to be shown in viewDidLoad and storing them in an array.  Just for example purposes I'm trying to only show 2 cells at first, one the user scrolls to bottom of screen the next cell will appear.  This is my code so far:

```
class DrinkViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var drinkTableView: UITableView!


  private let networkManager = NetworkManager.sharedManager

  fileprivate var totalDrinksArray: [CocktailModel] = []
  fileprivate var drinkImage: UIImage?

  fileprivate let DRINK_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER = "drinkCell"
  fileprivate let DRINK_SEGUE = "detailDrinkSegue"

  var drinksPerPage = 2
  var loadingData = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    drinkTableView.delegate = self
    drinkTableView.dataSource = self

    networkManager.getJSONData(function: urlFunction.search, catagory: urlCatagory.cocktail, listCatagory: nil, drinkType: "margarita", isList: false, completion: { data in

      self.parseJSONData(data)

    })
  }

}

extension DrinkViewController {

  //MARK: JSON parser
  fileprivate func parseJSONData(_ jsonData: Data?){
    if let data = jsonData {

      do {
        let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]//Parses data into a dictionary

        // print(jsonDictionary!)
        if let drinkDictionary = jsonDictionary!["drinks"] as? [[String: Any]] {
          for drink in drinkDictionary {
            let drinkName = drink["strDrink"] as? String ?? ""
            let catagory = drink["strCategory"] as? String
            let drinkTypeIBA = drink["strIBA"] as? String
            let alcoholicType = drink["strAlcoholic"] as? String
            let glassType = drink["strGlass"] as? String
            let drinkInstructions = drink["strInstructions"] as? String
            let drinkThumbnailUrl = drink["strDrinkThumb"] as? String

            let cocktailDrink = CocktailModel(drinkName: drinkName, catagory: catagory, drinkTypeIBA: drinkTypeIBA, alcoholicType: alcoholicType, glassType: glassType, drinkInstructions: drinkInstructions, drinkThumbnailUrl: drinkThumbnailUrl)

            self.totalDrinksArray.append(cocktailDrink)
          }
        }
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

      }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.drinkTableView.reloadData()
    }
  }


  //MARK: Image Downloader
  func updateImage (imageUrl: String, onSucceed: @escaping () -> Void, onFailure: @escaping (_ error:NSError)-> Void){
    //named imageData because this is the data to be used to get image, can be named anything
    networkManager.downloadImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, onSucceed: { (imageData) in
      if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
       self.drinkImage = image
      }
      onSucceed()//must call completion handler
    }) { (error) in
      onFailure(error)
    }
  }
}


//MARK: Tableview Delegates
extension DrinkViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    //return numberOfRows
    return drinksPerPage
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = drinkTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DRINK_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER) as! DrinkCell


    //get image from separate url
    if let image = totalDrinksArray[indexPath.row].drinkThumbnailUrl{//index out of range error here
      updateImage(imageUrl: image, onSucceed: {
        if let currentImage = self.drinkImage{
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.drinkImage.image = currentImage
          }
        }
      }, onFailure: { (error) in
        print(error)
      })
    }
    cell.drinkLabel.text = totalDrinksArray[indexPath.row].drinkName
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let image = totalDrinksArray[indexPath.row].drinkThumbnailUrl{
      updateImage(imageUrl: image, onSucceed: {
      }, onFailure: { (error) in
        print(error)
      })
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: DRINK_SEGUE, sender: indexPath.row)
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastElement = drinksPerPage
      if indexPath.row == lastElement {
         self.drinkTableView.reloadData()
      }
  }
}
```

I saw this post: [tableview-loading-more-cell-when-scroll-to-bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020315/tableview-loading-more-cell-when-scroll-to-bottom) and implemented the willDisplay function but am getting an "index out of range" error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView load more when scrolling to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588837/uitableview-load-more-when-scrolling-to-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me why you are doing this if you are getting all results at once then you don't have to limit your display since it is automatically managed by tableview. In tableview all the cells are reused so there will be no memory problem. UITableViewCell will be created when it will be shown.

So no need to limit the cell count.

**I dont now what you are doing in your code but:**

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let lastElement = drinksPerPage // no need to write this line
     if indexPath.row == lastElement { // if block will never be executed since indexPath.row is never equal to drinksPerPage.
     // As indexPath starts from zero, So its value will never be 2.
        self.drinkTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Your app may be crashing because may be you are getting only one item from server.

**If you seriously want to load more then you can try this code:**

Declare **numberOfItem** which should be equal to **drinksPerPage**

```
   var numberOfItem = drinksPerPage

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     //return numberOfRows
     return numberOfItem
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if indexPath.row == numberOfItem - 1 { 
        if self.totalDrinksArray.count > numberOfItem {
           let result = self.totalDrinksArray.count - numberOfItem
           if result > drinksPerPage {
              numberOfItem = numberOfItem + drinksPerPage
           }
           else {
              numberOfItem = result
           }   
           self.drinkTableView.reloadData()
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: I only want to show a specific number of tableview cells at once, then the user can decide if they want to load more.

Comment: @Rahul Dasgupta there is also something called comments.

Comment: @SwiftyJD is there any button for load more.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta there isn't but once the user scrolls to bottom of page it would load more.

Comment: @SwiftyJD If it worked then please upvote my answer.

Comment: ineed same could u help me